# Fixed position stop the element to fill the parent containber

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing a problem with fixed position. I have two rows on top of each other and I want them to look like this:

[image: working example]

which is what I want. Now because I need to use position fixed in my project to have the second row docked I changed the position to fixed. here is my css file:

```
.header {
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #4070CB;
color: #EFF0F2;
height: 5vw;
padding-top: 15px;
}

.story-board-header {
font-weight: bold;
background-color: #072e77;
color: #EFF0F2;
height: 3vw;
padding-top: 15px;
position:fixed;
}
```

Now here is what I get :
[image: not working]

As you see the second div does not fill all its container.
Also here is my jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vfvnzk4/2/)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `width: 100%`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4070CB;
  color: #EFF0F2;
  height: 5vw;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.story-board-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #072e77;
  color: #EFF0F2;
  height: 3vw;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row  header">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="col-xs-12  story-board-header">
      eweweweewew
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to link bootstrap.css to project:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pb7vptm8/1/

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure of what you are trying to accomplish.

Position fixed makes the element relative to the browser window and not it's container ([source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_position.asp)).

You can use both `width: 100%` or `left: 0; right: 0;` to make the element as width as the whole screen.

Fixed also causes the element to stay in place when you scroll the page. Is that what you want?